# Should I say all blessings aloud?

Tags: halacha, blessing, amen, loud-quiet

I find that most people have tendency to say most blessings (on food, going to the bathroom etc.) quietly to themselves. This [may](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/19119/answering-amen-to-quiet-berachoth) preclude others from having a chance to answer amen afterwards. Is the proper course of action to say all blessings aloud so that others can answer amen or should blessings be said in an undertone?

Comment: Whatever best helps your kavana.

Comment: IMHO kavana is helped by saying them deliberately and aloud. I know we don't mean it literally but the idea of people saying blessings "to themselves" worries me. We should be directing them to HaShem!

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok Tell that to Channa.

Comment: Don't overdo it on saying it aloud though. It can come off as "look at me". Use a voice loud enough for the person next to you perhaps, but no louder. i.e. ordinary quiet speech volume.

Answer (score 3):

One should say blessings aloud (source coming soon, b'li neder, but I think it's Sefer HaBeracha WeHilchotea). However if one knows that the people around him won't answer amen he should say it quietly (Ben Ish Hai).

Comment: The Ben Ish Chai shana alef parshas Balak halacha 2 says that it should be loud enough that the ears can hear it.

Comment: That's a separate issue.

Comment: What if you have always said it quietly and your partner has never said Amen? Is it considered that you know that they won't say it, and therefore a reason not to start saying the blessing aloud?